# Outlook screen flashing while adding signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I send bulk email to all the staff with default signature in Outlook email. The only problem I am facing is screen flashing. I have used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but it is not working. Please advise as to what could be done.

```
With OutMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
End With
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ws.Cells(I, 4).Value
    .Subject = ws.Cells(I, 1).Value & "-" & ws.Cells(I, 3).Value
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(rng) & vbNewLine & Signature
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code where you have the variable declarations?

Comment: Just take out the `.Display` line.

Comment: @Comintern It is usual, in my experience, to display to generate Signature

Comment: yes, if I remove the display, it is not adding any signature in outlook email.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call Display - the signature will be added even if you only call `MailItem.GetInspector`.

Secondly, you are concatenating 2 HTML strings - you cannot do that, they must be merged.

Comment: Can you please assist us on MailItem.GetInspector. Do I need to use it as OutMail.GetInspector. Aslo, please assist on merge the string. Thanks for all your support and help

Comment: You can read the GetInspector property. After that the HTMLBody property will contain the signature. As for merging the two bodies, you can either use the HTMLDocument object, or simply search for the positions of the "<body" tag, then find the position of the next ">" character, then insert your custom HTML.